# Failed to pip install uwsgi in virtualenv

Tags: python, uwsgi

Enviroment: CentOS6.4, python2.6
I created a virtualenv (envflask) and activated it, then pip install flask, everything was ok! But after creating another virtualenv (envuwsgi) and activating it, I failed to pip install uwsgi, the error messages are:

```
...
plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1731: 错误：被调用的对象‘<erroneous-expression>’不是一个函数

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1731: 错误：语句不起作用

plugins/python/python_plugin.c: 在函数‘uwsgi_python_harakiri’中:

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1737: 错误：‘struct uwsgi_python’没有名为‘tracebacker’的成员

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1740: 错误：‘struct uwsgi_python’没有名为‘tracebacker’的成员

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1740: 错误：传递‘uwsgi_concat2’的第 1 个参数时在不兼容的指针类型间转换

plugins/python/../../uwsgi.h:2733: 附注：需要类型‘char *’，但实参的类型为‘struct uwsgi_option *’

plugins/python/python_plugin.c: 在函数‘uwsgi_python_logger’中:

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1768: 错误：‘struct uwsgi_python’没有名为‘gil_get’的成员

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1768: 错误：被调用的对象‘<erroneous-expression>’不是一个函数

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1768: 错误：语句不起作用

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1771: 错误：‘PyObject’未声明(在此函数内第一次使用)

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1771: 错误：‘py_logging’未声明(在此函数内第一次使用)

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1771: 错误：双目运算符 * 操作数(‘struct uwsgi_option *’和‘struct uwsgi_option *’)无效

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1771: 错误：语句不起作用

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1773: 错误：‘py_logging_dict’未声明(在此函数内第一次使用)

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1773: 错误：双目运算符 * 操作数(‘struct uwsgi_option *’和‘struct uwsgi_option *’)无效

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1773: 错误：语句不起作用

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1775: 错误：‘py_getLogger’未声明(在此函数内第一次使用)

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1775: 错误：双目运算符 * 操作数(‘struct uwsgi_option *’和‘struct uwsgi_option *’)无效

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1775: 错误：语句不起作用

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1777: 错误：‘py_getLogger_args’未声明(在此函数内第一次使用)

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1777: 错误：双目运算符 * 操作数(‘struct uwsgi_option *’和‘struct uwsgi_option *’)无效

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1777: 错误：语句不起作用

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1779: 错误：语句不起作用

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1791: 错误：隐式声明函数‘PyObject_CallMethod’

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1791: 错误：expected expression before ‘)’ token

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1791: 错误：双目运算符 * 操作数(‘struct uwsgi_option *’和‘struct uwsgi_option *’)无效

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1795: 错误：‘struct uwsgi_python’没有名为‘gil_release’的成员

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1795: 错误：被调用的对象‘<erroneous-expression>’不是一个函数

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1795: 错误：语句不起作用

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1799: 错误：‘struct uwsgi_python’没有名为‘gil_release’的成员

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1799: 错误：被调用的对象‘<erroneous-expression>’不是一个函数

plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1799: 错误：语句不起作用

----------------------------------------
Command /home/Alex/myproject/envuwsgi/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/Alex/myproject/envuwsgi/build/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o9rNHV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/Alex/myproject/envuwsgi/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1 in /home/Alex/myproject/envuwsgi/build/uwsgi
Storing complete log in /home/Alex/.pip/pip.log
(envuwsgi)[Alex@Alex myproject]$
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you add the top of the error messages, or upload the full file somewhere?

Comment: and btw, you could use something like ``LANGUAGE=C pip ...`` to force the output in English, so it made others here easier to help you.

Answer (score 5):

You need header files for your python installation, so things like "PyObject" could be used by the uwsgi python plugin.

Try this:

```
yum install python-devel
```